# FindBugs Eclipse: specyfying exclude filter files relatively to project

Tags: eclipse, findbugs

We have Findbugs exclude filters defined in a `findbugs-excludes.xml` file in the root of our project.

Is it possible to use this file in FindBugs Eclipse **without using absolute path to this file**?

The problem that we have is that we have FindBugs configured in **project specific** settings in Eclipse and we want be able to propagate changes in FindBugs configuration by just svn commiting `.settings` directory.

But if it's configured giving absolute path we will need to ask each project member to update his FindBugs settings manually, giving a correct path in his file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using a relative path seems to work.

I have a global findbugs filter file in one project that every project uses.  In .settings/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.core.prefs of each project, I have:

> excludefilter0=../other.project/findbugs-global-excludes.xml|true

If this works it should work for a relative path to the same project.

I'm using version 2.0.1.20120712 of the findbugs plugin, for what it's worth.

Comment: It turned out that even if in Eclipse it looks like absolute path is set, it was stored as a relative path in configuration file and no other teammates needed to do anything like this.